# Passing a hash with a double splat only when the lambda requests one

Tags: ruby, hash, lambda

I have a `lambda` in a variable, whose argument signature I do not know. I want to pass an options hash to it with `**`, but only if it requires options.

So far, I have this:

```
def call_func(func, *args, **options)
    if func.arity < 0
        func[*args, **options]
    else
        func[*args]
    end
end
```

But this only works for lambdas like

```
lambda { |x, y| x + y }
```

or

```
lambda { |x, **opts| opts[:y] + x }
```

but fails for lambdas that consume an array of arguments, like

```
lambda { |*args| args.join ", " }
```

Is there a way I can detect for a lambda whose signature only consumes an array of arguments while not requesting an option hash?

Answer (score 1):

In `*args` case, the `arity` is `-1`. To separate all the cases with when there is no argument, you can do `nonzero?` instead of `< 0`.

Comment: This does not entirely solve the problem, as `arity` cannot distinguish between `lambda { |*args, **opts| ... }` and `lambda { |*args| ... }`.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien You cannot find such distinction between them anywhere. `|*args, **opts|` can accept whatever `|*args|` can, and vice versa.

Comment: I see. So it seems, my question is based on a misunderstanding of the way ruby processes arguments. Thanks for the clarification!